# Powering a 5v relay from a 12v power supply

Tags: voltage, ohms-law

I have a relay which is rated for 5v.  My power supply is 12v.

I have measured the resistance across the coil as 400 ohm.

If I place the relay in series with a resistor that is 560 ohm, would it correctly lower the voltage to 5v?

Or is there something more complicated going on, given that the relay is electromagnetic and not a passive component?

Comment: You can think of the relay's coil as a resistor. So yes, a resistor can be used. But check coil power first then coil resistance from datasheet. This will tell you required coil current *(P=I^2 × R)*. From Ohm's Law, you can calculate required series resistance for voltage drop. The power dissipation of that series resistor is important. Don't forget to take it into account.

Answer (score 22, accepted):

Your relay is rated for 5 V and you know its DC resistance is 400 Ω.  That means it draws (5 V)/(400 Ω) = 12.5 mA.

Yes, a resistor would work to drive this relay from 12 V.  The resistor needs to drop 7 V with 12.5 mA going thru it.  From Ohms law it needs to be (7 V)/(12.5 mA) = 560 Ω.  Your calculation is therefore correct.

You should also consider the power dissipation of the resistor.  It will be (7 V)(12.5 mA) = 85 mW.  That's within what a "⅛ W" resistor can handle, like something in a 0805 case.

Yes, that's about all there is to it.

Comment: Thank you very much, I appreciate your detailed response.